# ImportError PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, path, package

I am having trouble importing pandas, numpy and other modules into Pycharm. When I run python through ipython notebooks pandas, numpy, and other modules work fine. I am pretty sure this is a path problem. I have been to the Project interpreter settings in PyCharm to try to add the path where pandas and numpy are located on my computer, but I can't find the packages. I used easy_install and pip to install most of the packages, so I don't know where to find them. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed those modules in whatever the active project interpreter is? You might find using a project-specific `virtualenv` helps you keep the requirements neater.

Comment: You can run `help(numpy)` or `help(pandas)` etc in Python where it works to get the location. It may be on the very top of the help message.

Comment: import both in a shell and do `numpy.__file__` and `pandas.__file__`, it seems you most likely have more than one python2/3 installation